# Rake aborted! uninitialized constant knowit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am standing up a new Ubuntu server running MySQL. I have Capistrano set up on my development server and am trying to deploy:cold after running deploy:setup. After the deploy script tries to run

```
executing "cd /home/adm1n/www/knowit/releases/20121112152400 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
```

I keep getting this message:

```
Rake Aborted!
uninitialized constant knowit
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

Any idea where this constant would be defined? This project is almost entirely new (rails new app Blah). Any suggestions on how I should attempt to troubleshoot this? Thx.

I'm running:

- Rake 0.9.2.2
- Ruby 1.9.3p194
- Capistrano 2.13.5
- Bundler 1.1.5
- Rails 3.2.8
- rvm 1.15.7

UPDATE: knowit is the name of my app. So there apparently there is something not initializing. Not sure where how to troubleshoot this.

UPDATE: Here is my routes.rb file (very basic)

```
 Knowit::Application.routes.draw do
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
 end
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?  What version of Rake, what version of Capistrano. What version of Bundler?  What version of Ruby?

Comment: I'm running Rake 0.9.2.2, Ruby 1.9.3p194, Capistrano 2.13.5, Bundler 1.1.5, Rails 3.2.8, rvm 1.15.7

Comment: Please run that command again with `--trace` appended.

Comment: @RyanBigg Here is the output after running the command with --trace: [link](http://gist.github.com/4075361)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it's coming from inside `config/routes.rb`. Please show us the contents of that file.

Comment: Will provide config/routes in a moment. I just noticed something weird  when I run `rvm info` command: [link](https://gist.github.com/4075407). Notice how there are two slashes in the path underneath /home/admin/.rvm//

Comment: I'm reinstalling rvm on my server. If you notice "Knowit" in my routes.rb header is spelled with a capital "K", but the output is saying "know it" us the uninitialized constant. I believe this is referring to a gemset named "know it" with a lowercase "k". If the path to my gemset is screwed up as it appears to be with the double slash, this may be the source of the problem. Will let you know shortly.